# condition check replaced by bitwise operator

Tags: c

```
int x1 =-2 ;//any value
if(x1 < 0)
   x1 = 0;
```

I am trying by using bitwise operator

```
int result = !(x1 >> 31) & (((~x1 + 1) >> 31) & 1);
    x1 = result !=0 ? x1:result;
```

I don't want to use the conditional operator to explore more use of binary operator .There is no any other intension behind this .If any way is there please let me know .
Is there any way to do so ??

Comment: Why you don't want to use the condition operator?

Comment: just i want to try with binary operator only ..It is for understanding purpose only !!no intension ..If possible then please let me know .

Comment: Don't do such horrible things in real code. Nowadays compilers are most times quite smart to figure out when such rewriting is adequate on a given platform.

Comment: @JensGustedt. Yes is true, the today compilers have magic optimizations, but that is because some people think ... :)

Comment: @SergioFormiggini, exactly. That is why this is a bad question to ask in the first place. The whole learning and thinking experience is somehow jeopardized.

Comment: @JensGustedt. You've to think that in some cases, using MCUs and their tools, you may obtain very good results changing the mode in which data are elaborated! Not is always true that the compiler optimizations are able to obtain the results that our mind can!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming 32 bit integer and two's compliment, would the following be OK?

```
unsigned int x = (unsigned int)-2;
x &= (x >> 31) - 1;
```

---

I used `unsigned` because according to the standard

> The result of `E1 >> E2` is `E1` right-shifted `E2` bit positions. .... If `E1` has a signed type and a negative value, the
>   resulting value is implementation-defined.

Comment: You could use `(sizeof(int) * 8) - 1` instead of `31` for platform independance.

Comment: just one curiosity purpose ,multiplication operator can we replace by any binary operator in your case ??

Comment: @studinstru No. The point was that `(x>>31)^1` converts a negative number to `0`, a non-negative to `1`. Then you get `0` multiplying x and `0`. The current variant just uses bit arithmetic.

Comment: yes ..That is also good option to do twos complement .Can you update your answer with 2s complement also ??

Comment: @studinstru It is two's compliment already.

Comment: The shift yields `0` or `-1`. the subtraction then gives `-1` which works, or `-2` not so much.

Comment: sorry my mistake ..It true !!I was trying some other way ..;)

Comment: @user3386109 `x >> 31` is either `1` (for negatives) or `0`. Then, `-1` gives `0` or `0xFFFFFFFF` respectively.

Comment: Ah, I somehow missed the fact that you changed the variable to `unsigned`. Ok, the code works then. I guess you fooled me by setting an `unsigned` to a negative number ;)

Comment: @user3386109 Shifting negative signed integers is undefined in C/C++, that's why I made it `unsigned`.